# How do I set the width and height of a character in CSS

Tags: css

I am currently trying to make a page where all of the character's widths and heights are the same.

Comment: do you mean font size?

Comment: [font-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size)?

Comment: no I mean I want to make each and every character be 10px by 10px, fonts tend not to have the same width for all characters even when the font-size is specified

Comment: You cannot. And I don’t really think you want “.” to be as wide and as tall as “W”. If you explain what you are trying to achieve, we might find a solution to that. My guess is that the solution is to use a table where each cell contains one character (or to use a clumsy CSS imitation of that), but I’d like to see the problem. (Setting up a crossword puzzle?)

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that, but you can use a monospace font and set the height you want:

```
#something {
    font: (the height you want it to be)px monospace;
}
```

[Here is a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/zrmTa/1/)

It will look like this:
[image]

Comment: @user2464246 It means that each letter is the same width. (see my edit, I added an image)

Comment: Setting `font-size` sets the height of the font. The heights of characters vary and are generally much smaller than the height of the font. Setting font to monospace sets the advance width of characters; the widths of the characters vary. And relationship between the advance width and the font size is font-dependent (set by the font designer).

Answer (score 1):

```
* {
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    line-height: 10px;
}
```

This should make all the text the same height, spacing and family.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this for all characters you will want to use a mono-space font and set the font-size to 1em.  An `em` is equal to the width of the letter 'm' in the font and size all the letters are the same width, you will have them be same height and width.